# How to avoid mutating objects from session scope fixtures in PyTest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

What is the best way to avoid side effects on objects returned from session-scoped fixtures?

My recipe is to wrap a session-scoped fixture with a function-scoped one, which returns a copy of the original object. Is there anything built-in in PyTest for that? Some decorator maybe?

```
import pytest
from pandas import read_csv

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def _input_df():
    """Computationally expensive fixture, so runs once per test session.
    As an example we read in a CSV file 5000 rows, 26 columns into a pandas.DataFrame
    """
    df = read_csv('large-file.csv')

    return df


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def input_df(_input_df):
    """"This is a function-scoped fixture, which wraps around the session-scoped one
    to make a copy of its result."""
    return _input_df.copy()


def test_df_1(input_df):
    """Inadvertently, this test mutates the object from the input_df fixture"""
    # adding a new column
    input_df['newcol'] = 0
    # we now have 27 columns
    assert input_df.shape == (5000, 27)


def test_df_2(input_df):
    """But since we are getting a copy or the original this test still passes"""
    assert input_df.shape == (5000, 26)
```

Comment: Your approach with having an auxiliary fixture is fine. If you have lots of fixtures that should return object copies, I'd probably use [fixture factories](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#factories-as-fixtures), but it's basically the same idea.

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you not expect test_df_2 to pass? It is generally not a good idea to allow one test to impact the result of other tests. If the test collection is different, your tests results won't be consistent. 

If you want to modify _input_df.copy() in each tests, return the reference of object from input_df  fixture.

Comment: @hoefling, could you post a rewrite of the above using fixture factory?

Answer (score 2):

You should return the copy function object from input_df fixture without instantiating it:

```
import pytest
from pandas import read_csv

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def _input_df():
    """Computationally expensive fixture, so runs once per test session.
    As an example we read in a CSV file 5000 rows, 26 columns into a pandas.DataFrame
    """
    df = read_csv('large-file.csv')

    return df


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def input_df(_input_df):
    """"This is a function-scoped fixture, which wraps around the session-scoped one
    to make a copy of its result."""
    return _input_df.copy


def test_df_1(input_df):
    """Inadvertently, this test mutates the object from the input_df fixture"""
    # adding a new column
    input_df()['newcol'] = 0
    # we now have 27 columns
    assert input_df().shape == (5000, 27)


def test_df_2(input_df):
    """But since we are getting a copy or the original this test still passes"""
    assert input_df().shape == (5000, 26)
```

This code sample is working in my machine. test_df_2 test fails in this case.

Comment: My objective isn't to make the second test fail, to the contrary. I posted my solution, looking for something better to avoid writing two functions for every such fixture.

Comment: You should simply use copy.deepcopy() in that case. You `input_df.copy()` code would be replaced by `import copy; copy.deepcopy(_input_df.copy())`. It seems like `.copy()` method is doing shallow copy and that's why original data structure is being modified.
Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html